# unable to read XML file from server

Tags: android

I am reading XML file from server. The issue i am facing is that i have set urlconnection method to SET but when i debugged i checked it the method was POST and duw to which my inputstream.read() function is returning -1. so compiler is unable to read file from server.

My Code to read file from server is as follows:

```
urlString="some url";

                URL url = new URL(urlString);
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

                //connect
                urlConnection.connect();

                File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                //create a new file, to save the downloaded file
                File file = new File(SDCardRoot,"prahova.GIS");

                FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);

                //Stream used for reading the data from the internet
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                //this is the total size of the file which we are downloading
                totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();

                //create a buffer...
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int bufferLength = 0;

                while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read()) > 0 )
                {
                    fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                   downloadedSize += bufferLength;
                }

                fileOutput.close();
```

Comment: are you receiving an error?

Comment: i am not recieving an error but i am also not getting any file

Comment: can You show the real Url that is passed to HttpUrlConnection?

Comment: I would suggest logging what the input stream is returning so you can see if it is reading that is the problem or writing to the file

Comment: http://192.168.1.30/muneem/muneem.php?path=oglPrahova/Prahova.GIS

Comment: sorry for this sir but i am new to android plz tell me how to log this and check it

Comment: The URL you have linked to is a local URL, it is only accessible from your local network. Make sure the Android device / emulator is on the same network.

Comment: sir i am accesssing the server through same URL to show files and folder in ListView and it is working fine